# My recent unanswered question needs a rewrite - should I leave old one, edit old one, or something else?

Tags: support, editing, asking-questions, revisions

Re. [Surprisingly massive slowdown with CLI PHP(8.0/8.1/8.2) over NFS on 22.04.2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1459450/)

This has no answers. Over the last week, our team has actually eliminated several false positives - mainly that this has nothing to do with PHP or Laravel.

We are able to replicate the issue using both nginx and apache, as long as our requests are over 443 and also as long as the document (even a flat html document) is on an nfs server.

I am happy to do either - but it seems disingenuous to leave the old question up.

OTOH, if I edit it, people may think 'hm, I have read this already' and it's no longer the same.

**My guess is that I am meant to create a new question, and then delete the old one (or request that it be deleted.**

Comment: I see you have done a rewrite and added a bounty: great moves. I have undeleted an answer to your question (and converted to comment) which was really a 'I have the same issue...' answer; perhaps there may be some material to work on there...

Comment: +1 This is a great question, and well written.

Answer (score 4):

Edit the old one.

You can make it clear what you’ve changed when you edit it - so it’s not disingenuous.

When you edit, it’ll show as modified and jump to the top of the main page - so you should get more / new attention.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not delete your post.**  If you delete and repost, it's considered spam and noise and against policy, and you WILL get your old question undeleted by moderators, and the new one duped against it.  Therefore forcing you to be on the original question.

Deleting your post and reposting it as "new" is not going to help you as it's against policy.

In most cases, the situation is "We don't know how to help or start debugging" so there's no responses or attention.  Remember, everyone here is a volunteer - we don't know every answer or even how to necessarily begin debugging every issue.